# Porque no se muestra la t-upla con fecha minima?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla :

```
mysql> select * from Hospital;
+---+-----------+------------+
| H | PR        | F          |
+---+-----------+------------+
| 1 | Canarias  | 1984-02-01 |
| 2 | Cataluña  | 1996-04-03 |
| 3 | Canarias  | 2010-03-01 |
| 4 | Madrid    | 1999-01-01 |
| 5 | Madrid    | 2019-12-01 |
+---+-----------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Y quiero obtener el "H" en Madrid con la fecha mas antigua, por lo que uso la siguiente consulta:

```
mysql> select H,min(F) from Hospital where PR="Madrid" group by H;
+---+------------+
| H | min(F)     |
+---+------------+
| 4 | 1999-01-01 |
| 5 | 2019-12-01 |
+---+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

El tema es que me muestra dos t-uplas, y necesito la que tiene H=4, porque muestra dos t-uplas en vez de 1 ?

Con el comando "Describe" sale lo siguiente:

```
mysql> describe Hospital;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| H     | varchar(5)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| PR    | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| F     | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Y si le pones limit 1

Comment: Funciona, pero la idea es que la funcion MIN () haga eso de forma automatica

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La verdad es que es un tema bastante confuso. Espero poder aclararlo de forma sencilla.

Empiezo por la solución:

```
SELECT H FROM Hospital WHERE PR='Madrid'
  AND F=(
    SELECT MIN(F) FROM Hospital WHERE PR='Madrid'
  );
```

Y el dataset del que he partido, para que se puedan realizar las comprobaciones:

```
CREATE TABLE Hospital(
  H int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  PR varchar(10),
  F date
  );
INSERT INTO Hospital (PR, F) VALUES 
  ('Canarias','1984-02-01'),
  ('Cataluña','1996-04-03'),
  ('Canarias','2010-03-01'),
  ('Madrid','1999-01-01'),
  ('Madrid','2019-12-01');
```

Y ahora las aclaraciones:

- Olvidaos de la eficiencia, esta consulta requiere necesariamente dos pasos. A no ser que defináis la fecha `F` como `INDEX` y la resolváis por `ORDER BY`. En este caso tenéis que tener en cuenta que, si coinciden dos fechas, únicamente os mostrará el primer registro y no todos los que coincidan con esa fecha mínima.

> ```
> ALTER TABLE Hospital ADD INDEX(F);
> SELECT H FROM Hospital WHERE PR='Madrid' ORDER BY F LIMIT 1;
> ```

- Nunca, jamás, hagáis esto en una consulta de totales:

> ```
> SELECT H,MIN(F) FROM Hospital WHERE PR='Madrid';
> ```

Parece que funciona, pero sólo tenéis que probar con:

> `SELECT H,MAX(F) FROM Hospital WHERE PR='Madrid';`

Para comprobar que sigue dando el mismo resultado (suele ser el primero que encuentra), da igual que busquéis el máximo que el mínimo. La razón es porque SQL no funciona así. Un total y una proyección son operaciones algebraicas que no podemos mezclar. O calculamos un total o proyectamos, las dos cosas a la vez: no. Puedes buscar un mínimo con `MIN()` o localizar a qué registro corresponde un valor con `WHERE`. Pero hay que tener en cuenta que son dos operaciones diferentes.

- Y, por último, el `GROUP BY`. No forméis grupos a no ser que los necesitéis. Lo que hace SQL cuando se encuentra un `GROUP BY` es hacer montones independientes separados por los campos de agrupamiento, y calcular totales para cada grupo de forma separada. Si sólo os interesa Madrid, el `WHERE` está perfecto. No necesitamos los totales de otras autonomías.
- Y nunca, nunca jamás, agrupéis por una clave principal. Por definición, os van a salir tantos grupos como registros y, los totales de cada grupo, van a coincidir con el valor de cada registro. Así que, con una proyección, llegaríais al mismo resultado y a un coste computacional mucho menor. Siempre que agrupemos por un campo, éste debe tener valores que se repitan en diferentes registros.

Espero que esta respuesta os resulte de utilidad. Quedo a vuestra disposición para aclarar o ampliar cualquier detalle.

Answer (score 4):

**OPCIÓN 1**

Tu agrupamiento no va a funcionar por qué la columna H y la columna F son distintas en sus valores.

Yo dejaría la consulta así:

```
select H,min(F) from Hospital where PR="Madrid" GROUP BY H;
```

agrega al final el uso de

```
Limit 1
```

Para indicar que limite a un registro el resultado obtenido

**OPCIÓN 2**

Realizando una *CTE* dentro de la cual hacemos:

- Seleccionamos `H`, `PR` y `F`
- Hacemos uso de un `WHERE` donde indicamos que `F` es decir la fecha sea igual a:
- Dentro de paréntesis escribimos una sub query donde seleccionamos la fecha menor donde `PR` sea igual a `Madrid`
- Hacemos por fuera de la *CTE* un `SELECT` de las columnas que indicamos debe retornar de `Menor` que es el nombre que le dimos a la * CTE*

**Query**

```
WITH Menor AS(
    SELECT H, PR, F
    FROM demo WHERE F = (SELECT MIN(F) FROM demo WHERE PR = "Madrid")  
)SELECT H, PR, F FROM Menor;
```

**Resultado**

```
H   PR  F
4   Madrid  1999-01-01
```

O simplemente saca la consulta del contexto de la *CTE* y ejecutala y así debe funcionar:

```
SELECT H, PR, F
FROM demo 
WHERE F = (SELECT MIN(F) FROM demo WHERE PR = "Madrid");
```

Comment: lo intente, pero me sale el siguiente error :     ERROR 1140 (42000): In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'examen230119.Hospital.H'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es que, si por ejemplo hago la misma consulta pero quitando "H" de "select" me da 1 resultado(correcto), pero claro el dato que me interesa es la propia H :(

Comment: Lo que ocurre que no puedes agrupar el 4 y el 5 por qué son valores distintos, por eso te recomendaba el LIMIT 1 @K1k4ss0

Comment: ya lo solucione, se puede realizar una subquery de la siguiente forma:    mysql> select H from Hospital where F in (select Min(F) from Hospital where PR="Madrid"); y dara bien

Comment: Agrega tu solución como respuesta entonces @K1kss0

Comment: te dejé otra opción de solución @k1k4ss0 usando una **CTE** disponible desde MySQL 8

Comment: Buenos días @Aprendiz, coincido con una de tus soluciones. Aunque con alguno de tus comentarios discrepo. Te dejo mi respuesta para que podamos comentarlos.

Answer (score 1):

AL final se puede conseguir el resultado con una subconsulta:

```
mysql> select H from Hospital where F in (
       select Min(F) from Hospital where PR="Madrid");
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando MariaDB (No tengo MySQL a la mano) te propongo:

```
SELECT H 
  FROM (
    SELECT H 
         , MIN(F) 
      FROM Hospital 
     WHERE PR = 'Madrid' 
 ) SUB
```

Lo cual me devuelve:

[image: resultado en MariaDB]

Comment: Hola @AlvaroC., estás cometiendo un error muy habitual al buscar la correspondencia con el mínimo. Te lo aclaro en mi respuesta. Espero ayudarte.

Comment: @David. Te agradezco mucho. Tienes toda la razón.